Change Background-Color of portion of Text with Closedxml in Excel
Is there a way to change the background-color of a part of the text inside a cell? im aware of the richttext functions to change text-stylings but could no find anything for the background-color.
I tried to find a method within worksheet.Cell(x,y).RichText.Substring...

If I am not wrong, you can't even do that in Excel itself. So it should be no surprise that you can't do it in ClosexXML,

After a bit of research it seems like closedXML does not support this functionality. I think even excel itself cannot set several background colors to different portions of a cells content.
Here is a little demonstration of what you can do with richtext
